# when I do a 'make install' it does not create Directory

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, automake, permission-denied, make-install

This is my first attempt with autoconf, I changed and added some different code to a utility then I took the make.am and other files I needed, I modified them to work with what I wrote, into the same program. as it worked with that one, all I needed to change was the name and version and main.c and header file names. When I do, configure, then, make, it all goes well. it is when I get to the "make install" then I get this error, and I am not sure why.

```
Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/userx/Dropbox/mhsetroot-MAKE/src'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/userx/Dropbox/mhsetroot-MAKE/src'
/bin/bash ../config/mkinstalldirs /usr/local/bin
/usr/bin/install -c mhsetroot /usr/local/bin/mhsetroot
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/bin/mhsetroot': Permission denied
make[2]: *** [install-binPROGRAMS] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/userx/Dropbox/mhsetroot-MAKE/src'
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/userx/Dropbox/mhsetroot-MAKE/src'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

it does not let it make a directory. So, I tired it.

```
mkdir /usr/local/bin/mhsetroot
```

I get the same error, therefore it is **just** a permissions problem, right **?** 
If that is all that it is, then it should work on someone else's computer, just not mine? Also, then what permissions do I need to have set on **my** "local/bin" so that the "make install" will work without having to be in "sudo" mode first?

Answer (score 2):

Try doing it with 
`sudo make install`
command as you need to have root access for this.
So instead of typing `make install` in command, whenever you
get permission error, try putting `sudo` in beginning of command and then enter the root password. It works.
:)

Answer (score 1):

> I get the same error, therefore it is just a permissions problem, right ?

Right.  It cannot create `/usr/local/bin/mhsetroot`.

> If that is all that it is, then it should work on someone else's computer, just not mine?

It depends on what the permissions of `/usr/local/bin` is.

> Also, then what permissions do I need to have set on my "local/bin" so that the "make install" will work without having to be in "sudo" mode first?

It depends on what the permissions of `/usr/local/bin` is.  Usually you *will* need root permission to install there (e.g. `sudo make install`).  Alternately, you can set `DESTDIR` for `make install`:

```
make DESTDIR=/some/writable/path install
```

but that also might need more setup, too (e.g. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`).

Comment: yeah that is what it was a brain fart is all - I forgot - I was doing install instead of sudo install -- problem solved

Answer (score 0):

`make && make install` is not a single command, it is two.
`sudo make && install` will execute `make` as superuser, but the `&&` part is telling `make install` to wait until the first part has completed. 'make install' is it's own command, so what you need is:

```
sudo make && sudo make install
```

This is what I needed to do on slackware to get efl to build. I had exactly the same error as OP (searching it brought me here).

A more common example is

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

where these are more commonly written as 2 lines without the '&&'. You have to sudo both parts.